# In java protected membes access from diff package

Tags: java, protected, access-specifier

In Java, how can I access protected members in a different package?

```
package p1
    class base      
        protected int x

package p2
    import p1.*
    class derived extends base
        int x

class subderived extends derived
     int x
```

From `subderived` main I want to access `x` of `p1.base` as protected specification we can use only inheritance we can't use reference to access `base` `x`. To access `derived` `x` we can use `super.x`, but from `subderived`, how can we access `base.x`?

Answer (score 2):

Protected members are accessible from immediately derived and sub-derived classes without any qualifiers: rather than writing

```
base.x = 123;
```

you can write

```
x = 123;
```

and it will compile fine, as long as it is in a method of a derived class. However, in order for this to work, you need to remove members with the same name from the derived class itself: otherwise, the base member is *hidden*, and cannot be accessed through more than one level of inheritance hierarchy through the normal syntax of the language, i.e. without using *reflection*.

Comment: but isn't `derived.x` [hiding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html) `base.x`?

Comment: @WChargin You are correct, I missed the fact that there's `x` in the derived class hiding the `x` in the base. I doubt that that other `x` is put there intentionally, so I updated the answer to reflect this. Thanks!